# Conditions for the existence of a probability density function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Good evening, there is some conditions that a density function must respect to be correct? My point is, for example a distribution function is defined if it satisfies three conditions: It is non-decreasing, right continous and asymptotically bounded in 0,1. There is some similar condition for density function? A density must be necessarily continous? Thank you.

Comment: Nonnegative, measurable, integrates to 1.

Comment: With regard to the particular question of whether a density need be continuous: discontinuous densities over $\mathbb R$ are a dime a dozen. Consider the uniform density on any interval, for example.

Comment: Thank you For the answers. I have another (maybe obvious) question. If F(x) is not a Distribution function it can have a density?